# Complex ad-hoc polymorphism in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to use type class to simulate ad-hoc polymorphism and solve generic cases involving higher kinded types and so far can't figure out the correct solution.

What I'm looking for is to define something similar to:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances   #-}

infixl 0 >>>

-- | Type class that allows applying a value of type @fn@ to some @m a@
class Apply m a fn b | a fn -> b where
  (>>>) :: m a -> fn -> m b

-- to later use it in following manner:

(Just False) >>> True -- same as True <$ ma
(Just True) >>> id -- same as id <$> ma
Nothing >>> pure Bool -- same as Nothing >>= const $ pure Bool
(Just "foo") >>> (\a -> return a) -- same as (Just "foo") >>= (\a -> return a)
```

So far I've tried multiple options, none of them working.
Just a straight forward solution obviously fails:

```
instance (Functor m) => Apply m a b b where
  (>>>) m b = b <$ m

instance (Monad m) => Apply m a (m b) b where
  (>>>) m mb = m >>= const mb

instance (Functor m) => Apply m a (a -> b) b where
  (>>>) m fn = fmap fn m

instance (Monad m, a' ~ a) => Apply m a (a' -> m b) b where
  (>>>) m fn = m >>= fn
```

As there are tons of fundep conflicts (all of them) related to the first instance that gladly covers all the cases (duh).

I couldn't work out also a proper type family approach:

```
class Apply' (fnType :: FnType) m a fn b | a fn -> b where
  (>>>) :: m a -> fn -> m b

instance (Functor m) => Apply' Const m a b b where
  (>>>) m b = b <$ m

instance (Monad m) => Apply' ConstM m a (m b) b where
  (>>>) m mb = m >>= const mb

instance (Functor m, a ~ a') => Apply' Fn m a (a' -> b) b where
  (>>>) m mb = m >>= const mb

instance (Functor m, a ~ a') => Apply' Fn m a (a' -> m b) b where
  (>>>) m fn = m >>= fn


data FnType = Const | ConstM | Fn | FnM

type family ApplyT a where
  ApplyT (m a) = ConstM
  ApplyT (a -> m b) = FnM
  ApplyT (a -> b) = Fn
  ApplyT _ = Const
```

Here I have almost the same issue, where the first instance conflicts with all of them through fundep.

The end result I want to achieve is somewhat similar to the infamous [magnet pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/) sometimes used in Scala.

**Update:**

To clarify the need for such type class even further, here is a somewhat simple example:

```
-- | Monad to operate on
data Endpoint m a = Endpoint { runEndpoint :: Maybe (m a) } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
```

So far there is no huge need to have mentioned operator `>>>` in place, as users might use the standard set of `<$ | <$> | >>=` instead. (Actually, not sure about `>>=` as there is no way to define `Endpoint` in terms of `Monad`)

Now to make it a bit more complex:

```
infixr 6 :::

-- | Let's introduce HList GADT
data HList xs where
  HNil :: HList '[]
  (:::) :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)

-- Endpoint where a ~ HList
endpoint :: Endpoint IO (HList '[Bool, Int]) = pure $ True ::: 5 ::: HNil 

-- Some random function
fn :: Bool -> Int -> String
fn b i = show b ++ show i

fn <$> endpoint -- doesn't work, as fn is a function of a -> b -> c, not HList -> c
```

Also, imagine that the function `fn` might be also defined with `m String` as a result. That's why I'm looking for a way to hide this complexity away from the API user.

Worth mentioning, I already have a type class to convert `a -> b -> c` into `HList '[a, b] -> c`

Comment: Aw come on... why do so many people downvote lately without giving a reason? IMO this is perhaps not a _particularly useful_ question (why do you want that?), but it's certainly well-specified and it does show enough research effort to be ok.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Might be related to mention of Scala? :)

Answering on "why do I want that" is to unify possible operations over my monad under a single operator `>>>`, otherwise I'd have to introduce them per-case and it might be quite a lot of _noise_ in the final API look-and-feel.

Comment: Well, a good rule of thumb for typeclasses is: if you can't write anything useful that's _polymorphic_ over the class, then it's probably not a good idea to use a class in the first place. In your case, I don't see what the `>>>` really gains over using `<$`, `<$>` and `>>=` directly.

Comment: Okay, example. I have following monad: `data Foo m a = Foo { underlying: m (Maybe a) }`. As far as `a` is some primitive, you're totally correct and usual operators are fine.

Now, let's imagine `a :: HList '[_p0, _p1]`. Instead of providing function `_p0 -> _p1 -> out`, users are "doomed" to deal with `HList '[_p0, _p1] -> out` instead, which _might_ be not the best experience.

Comment: I'm not really convinced yet, but maybe this would in fact be a good use case. Why don't you elaborate a bit more and add it to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to abstract over `HList`s, just do that. Don't muddle things by introducing a possible monad wrapper at every argument, it turns out to be [quite complicated indeed](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/monadic.pdf). Instead do the wrapping and lifting at the function level with all the usual tools. So:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

data HList a where
    HNil :: HList '[]
    (:::) :: x -> HList xs -> HList (x : xs)

class ApplyArgs args i o | args i -> o, args o -> i where
    apply :: i -> HList args -> o

instance i ~ o => ApplyArgs '[] i o where
    apply i _ = i

instance (x ~ y, ApplyArgs xs i o) => ApplyArgs (x:xs) (y -> i) o where
    apply f (x ::: xs) = apply (f x) xs
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the only sane way is to provide only limited support for some subcases. Thanks